# How to get all GPS coordinates between start and end points on a route for Google Maps?

Tags: gps

Is there a way online that I can use to get all the gps points on a route between two points on a Google Map? i.e, if I give starting point and destination point, I need to get all the GPS points on that particular route.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everybody wants that, except the owner of that data. (TomTom/TeleAtlas via Google).
Normally you can't get that via an official api. There is or was a private web service from Google that sends the route compressed and decoded.

But legally you cannot get that data.

If you want such vector data (the coordinates) then you have to use `OpenStreetMap` via an Api like `RouteMe`.